# How to skip blank rows using CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a text string from which using the library I would like to skip the blanks inside the "*" delimiters. The problem I find is that when there is "**" it takes it as a row and should not be so.

TEXT:

```
ISA*00**00**09*005070479TMAN*01*FBLP*190305*2029**00405*000033241*0*
```

What I´m getting :

```
auth_inf_qua;sec_inf_qua;inter_id_qua;inter_sender_id;inter__id_qua2;inter_reciev_id;date_isa;hour_date;inter_cntrlver_num;inter_ctrol_num;ackn_rqstd

00;;00;;09;005070479TMAN;01;FBLP;190305;2029;00405
```

I´ve tried :

```
csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = row => row.All( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace );
```

```
C#

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(texto))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
//which configuration I should use
                csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
                csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "*";
                csv.Context.ReaderConfiguration.;

                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<IsaMap>();
                ;
                var IsaRecords = new List<isa>();

                while (csv.Read())
                {// maybe a condition
                    switch (csv.GetField(0))
                    {
                        case "ISA":
                            IsaRecords.Add(csv.GetRecord<isa>());
                            break;

                        default:
                            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown record type.");
                    }
                }
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(rutasal))
                using (var csv2 = new CsvWriter(writer))
                {
                    csv2.WriteRecords(IsaRecords);
                }

            }
        }

        public class isa
        {
            public string auth_inf_qua { get; set; }
            public string sec_inf_qua { get; set; }
            public string inter_id_qua { get; set; }
            public string inter_sender_id { get; set; }
            public string inter__id_qua2 { get; set; }
            public string inter_reciev_id { get; set; }
            public string date_isa { get; set; }
            public string hour_date { get; set; }
            public string inter_cntrlver_num { get; set; }
            public string inter_ctrol_num { get; set; }
            public string ackn_rqstd { get; set; }
        }

        public sealed class IsaMap : ClassMap<isa>
        {
            public IsaMap()
            {
                Map(m => m.auth_inf_qua).Index(1);
                Map(m => m.sec_inf_qua).Index(2);
                Map(m => m.inter_id_qua).Index(3);
                Map(m => m.inter_sender_id).Index(4);
                Map(m => m.inter__id_qua2).Index(5);
                Map(m => m.inter_reciev_id).Index(6);
                Map(m => m.date_isa).Index(7);
                Map(m => m.hour_date).Index(8);
                Map(m => m.inter_cntrlver_num).Index(9);
                Map(m => m.inter_ctrol_num).Index(10);
                Map(m => m.ackn_rqstd).Index(11);
            }
        }
    }
```

What I would like to get:

```
auth_inf_qua;sec_inf_qua;inter_id_qua;inter_sender_id;inter__id_qua2;inter_reciev_id;date_isa;hour_date;inter_cntrlver_num;inter_ctrol_num;ackn_rqstd

00;00;09;005070479TMAN;01;FBLP;190305;2029;U;00405;000033241;0
```

Comment: You don't want to skip a row.  You want to skip an empty field. There is no configuration to skip fields.  You could change your indexes in the `ClassMap` if the empty fields are always in the same location.  i.e. `Map(m => m.sec_inf_qua).Index(3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to skip empty fields, not empty rows.  If you know the location of the fields, you can specify them in `Index()` in your `ClassMap<isa>`. An empty row would look like `***************`.

```cs
public sealed class IsaMap : ClassMap<isa>
{
    public IsaMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.auth_inf_qua).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.sec_inf_qua).Index(3);
        Map(m => m.inter_id_qua).Index(5);
        Map(m => m.inter_sender_id).Index(6);
        Map(m => m.inter__id_qua2).Index(7);
        Map(m => m.inter_reciev_id).Index(8);
        Map(m => m.date_isa).Index(9);
        Map(m => m.hour_date).Index(10);
        Map(m => m.inter_cntrlver_num).Index(12);
        Map(m => m.inter_ctrol_num).Index(13);
        Map(m => m.ackn_rqstd).Index(14);
    }
}
```